# Django_db mark for django parametrized tests

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have been learning django for the past few weeks and I tried using the  parametrizing fixtures and test functions and from what I understood I can simply run multiple tests at once. With the parametrized test I am trying to test functions, which are found in all models. I read the documentation, but sadly, as soon as I tried it I got the following error message `Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.`. I did read about the error and possible fixes and what I found was to create an autouse fixture and put it in `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def enable_db_access_for_all_tests(db):
    pass
```

Sadly, this change made 0 difference and I received the same exact error after running the test. I did also try to use the django_db mark to grant the test access to the database, but that also did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realize it, but the above WAS "working".  If you look closely at the error, it changed.  `Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.` is still there, incorrectly, but also, for me anyway, it was running migrations, which I didn't want it to do, and it was crashing on some old data migration.  Adding `--nomigrations` to the command resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a decorator @pytest.mark.django_db above the function that is concerned
or you can also use @pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True) , this helps pytest to tell django that the concerned function will require database access